How to delete flatbuffers received from ZeroMQ
I'm looking for an example in C++ 11 to delete flatbuffers received by ZeroMQ.
I have two applications: Publisher and Subscriber.
I know that on the Publisher (sender) side, that the FlatBufferBuilders I use are RAII. Those work. But on the receiver side, do these flatbuffer messages clear themselves in some way? I think I need to move or copy each message. I'm not sure sure how that should be done exactly (API methods? memcpy? make my own wrapper objects?). There are no good examples for what I need with both flatbuffers and ZeroMQ PUB/SUB - I've looked.
zmq_msg_close, non-deterministic when it does anything, and it adds to the confusion. According to zmq docs, it cleans resources after the user has "indicated" it is no longer needed. Could it possibly step on messages I need to store in a temp data structure to use later in the program?
SUBSCRIBER APP (C++ app, but psuedo codish representation here for simplicity) ... repeat in a while(1) loop ...
zmq_msg_t zMsg;
zmq_msg_init(&zMsg);
int numBytesReceived = zmq_msg_recv(&zMsg, subSocket, 0);
if(numBytesReceived != -1)
{
   const my::fbs::MyMessage * myReceivedMessage =
      my::fbs::GetMyMessage(zmq_msg_data(&zMsg));
   //switch on MessageType (union)
   const my::fbs::SelectedSubMessage * pSSM = myReceivedMessage->get_content_as(CaseType);

   // **How to eventually delete the fbs messages later in the program?
   // move them into something else? copy them? use flat cpp gen objects "T"? DetachedBuffer? or leave them as is?**
}

zmq_msq_close(zMsg); 


I have written client/server, pub/sub test apps.
Each time I would watch memory size by procid.
I would determine if memory size decreased after zmq_msg_close - it does not (but zmq_msg_close is not deterministic I know)
I can't call delete explicity on the received flatbuffer. They are "owned" as subclasses of private Table.

I'm pretty certain that zmq_msg_t's are independent of ZMQ's sockets and contexts (thing that would be impacted by calls to zmq_close() or other "we're done here" calls such as zmq_ctx_shutdown. Msg are reference counted, so everywhere you have a reference to the message would have to call zmq_msg_close, and zmq itself would have to have finished with the message. Also note the behaviour of your memory allocator! Just because a program has "freed" some memory does not mean the C/C++ allocator has given the memory back to the OS. Mostly, these days, it won't, so you won't see a reduction.

@bazza That's a good point about that the allocator. Good point too that zmq msg is reference counted. It's difficult to say how many references counts zmq has vs, passing around and storing raw fb pointers. I'm thinking that use of flatc -gen-object-api may help as they copy data to smart pointers. Weird part is there are no errors. Not yet that is. zmq_msg_close while pass around and store the same raw fb ...well I'm thinking with more traffic either zmq is going to pull the memory, who knows when - or fb will never release the pointers (no explicit delete can be called) leading to mem leaks
